# Switching over from mysql to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

As the title states, I'm switching from old MySQL_statements to PDO. I am having a problem however when trying to see if `'tableitem'` exists already, then if it does I want to grab `'tableitem2'`, and if the `'tableitem'` doesn't exist, I want to set `'tableitem2'` to 1. Here is my old MySQL code and below I will state what I have tried.

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE user_ip='$user_ip' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) )
{
  $_SESSION['stage'] = $row[1];
}
else
{
   $_SESSION['stage'] = 1;
    $strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (user_ip, stage) VALUES ('$user_ip','$stage')";
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The above worked, but now I wish to switch to PDO statements.
Here if what I have tried with PDO statements:

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`stage`) FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE `user_ip` = ?";
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(array($user_ip)); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($result->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        $_SESSION['stage'] = $row[1];
         }
  else {
      $_SESSION['stage'] = 1;
    $result = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `BPGUV` (`user_ip`, `stage`) VALUES (:user_ip, :stage)";
    $result->execute(
        array(
        ':user_ip' => $user_ip,
        ':stage' => 1
        )
    );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, I have connected to the database using PDO and am able to use MySQL commands using PDO, just can't seem to transfer the above code into PDO statements properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`stage`) FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE `user_ip` = ?";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array($user_ip)); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
  /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($number_of_rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION['stage'] = $number_of_rows;
 }
  else {
    $_SESSION['stage'] = 1;
    $result = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` (`user_ip`, `stage`) VALUES (:user_ip, :stage)");
    $result->execute(
        array(
        ':user_ip' => $user_ip,
        ':stage' => 1
        )
    );
}
```

In your first query, you're passing `$user_ip` directly inside the query, instead of binding it later or passing as a parameter. Currently, the query was being taken as:

```
SELECT COUNT(`stage`) 
FROM `TABLENAME` 
WHERE `user_ip` = 8.8.8.8
```

which, as you know, is wrong syntax.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, I edited my post and tried using your code, but it doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @user2582299 Whoops! I didn't notice it at first. It should have been `$number_of_rows` instead of `$result->fetchColumn()` inside the if-statement. Fixed now.

Comment: I was also missing a ')'
 $result = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` (`user_ip`, `stage`)";
should be stage')");

Comment: How would I get the 'stage' from the table? like where I have:
 $_SESSION['stage'] = $number_of_rows;
example:
 $_SESSION['stage'] = $results['stage'];

Comment: @user2582299 Change `SELECT COUNT(stage)` to `SELECT stage` and then you'll have to loop over the resultset.